# binary file generated by gcc objcopy has a size much larger than sum of 'text' and 'data' in gcc size output

Tags: gcc, elf, objcopy

I use `objcopy -S -g -O binary test.elf test.bin` to get a `.bin` file from `.elf`.

```
$ ll test.bin 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 hongzhuwang md_psw 1472320 Oct 28 19:07 test.bin
```

```
$ size test.elf 
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 173062    6328 6605424 6784814  67872e test.elf
```

The size of `test.bin` is apparently larger than the sum of *text* and *data* in `test.elf`. Why is there such a huge difference? Which sections will `objcopy` copy from `.elf` into `.bin`?

Comment: Showing output from `readelf -WS test.elf` is likely to improve an answer you will get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some `NOBITS`sections between `PROGBITS` sections in the linker script. The binary file will occupy a continuous address space, so the `NOBITS` sections' space are filled by zero by `objcopy`. I think that's the root cause for the difference.